# How to get a bulk of user's profiles in sharepoint 2013

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to get a list of users with their email addressess, profile pictures and if possible telephone numbers.

The best option would get it as part of `Lists.GetListItemChangesSinceToken` request or a request just after it with a list of account names / emails.

**What I've tried:**

- with `<ExpandUserField>TRUE</ExpandUserField>` as part of `Lists.GetListItemChangesSinceToken` I only get a little extra data: 
  `ows_Author="1;#Admin AdminName,#login\name,#emailaddress,#sipaddress,#Admin AdminName"`
  Didn't find any other way to expand the Author field.
- With the search api I can get a speciefic user with the query: 
  `_api/search/query?sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&querytext='accountname:i:0#.f|membership|admin@company.com'` 
  I tried a lot of ways to get several users but i couldn't:

- `querytext='accountname:or(i:0#.f|membership|admin@company.com i:0#.f|membership|admin2@company.com)'`
- `querytext='accountname:any("i:0#.f|membership|admin@company.com", "i:0#.f|membership|admin2@company.com")'`
- `querytext='accountname:or(i:0#.f|membership|admin@company.com i:0#.f|membership|admin2@company.com)'&enablefql=true`
- `querytext='accountname:or(i:0#.f|membership|admin@company.com i:0#.f|membership|admin2@company.com)'&enablefql=true&enablequeryrules=true`

with rest api `/_api/web/siteusers` with a filter I got several users **but** it returns not enough data. No telephone numbers or profile pictures.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i tried a lot of options and completely missed the right one:

```
_api/search/query?
sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'&
querytext='ac‌​‌​countname:i:0#.f|membership|admin@company.com accountname:i:0#.f|membership|admin2@company.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you found an answer within the web services but here's an alternative approach (put together quickly in notepad based on a prior project so may need some refinement, however it should give you the general idea):

```
var siteName = "";

using (var site = new SPSite(siteName))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
        var userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

        var profiles = new List<SPUsersEntity>();

        foreach (UserProfile profile in userProfileManager)
        {
                            profiles.Add(LoadItems( profile.DisplayName,
                                                    profile.AccountName,
                                                    Convert.ToString(currentProfile[PropertyConstants.Title].Value),
                                                    Convert.ToString(currentProfile[PropertyConstants.Department].Value),
                                                    Convert.ToString(currentProfile[PropertyConstants.PictureUrl].Value),
                                                    Convert.ToString(currentProfile[PropertyConstants.Manager].Value),
                                                    Convert.ToString(currentProfile[PropertyConstants.SPSDepartment].Value),
                                                    Convert.ToString(currentProfile[PropertyConstants.WorkEmail].Value) ,
                                                    Convert.ToString(currentProfile[PropertyConstants.WorkPhone].Value)));
    }
    }
}

public SPUsersEntity LoadItems(string name, string username, string title, string department, string pictureURL, string manager, string team, string email, string phone)
{
    var usersEntity = new SPUsersEntity
    {
        Name = name ,
        Username = username ,
        Title = title ,
        Department = department ,
        Picture = pictureURL ,
        Manager = manager ,
        Team = team ,
        Email = email ,
        WorkPhone = phone
    };

    return usersEntity;
}

public class SPUsersEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```